# Android - start Activity and back Issue

Tags: android

I have one issue that currently face.

For example as below:

**Activity A**
to
**Activity B**
to
**Activity B**

then in third page, i click back, is go to first page, not go to second page.

i use like below code for go next page in Activity B.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(act, Activity_B.class);
intent.putExtra("Sample ID", "1");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

i use below code to back in Activity B.

```
super.onBackPressed();
```

So does anyone face this problem for back button issue ?

please advice.

thank you.

Comment: You want to do like this .`A->B->C->B`？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove from your code this line:

```
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Look [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) for more information

Answer (score 0):

If you are targetting Android 4.1 (API level 16) or higher you can set the up navigation in the manifest.

And in the activity, when you go back it will go to the parent.

Android developer dox: 
[Providing Up Navigation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html)